# How to change child text using jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery mouseenter/leave to try to change the (currently-hovered-over) TEXT inside a container without changing any other child elements.

I'm using this on top of a live 3rd party website - this means I have no control over the HTML code, which gives me the following issues:

- I don't know how many child elements are in the parent container
- the HTML tags (both parent and children) could be anything from LI, to IMG, to A, to SPAN, to H1, etc
- the position of the text I need to change will vary from 1st to last
  and anything in-between

I've tried the following (nameX and indexX are used to identify the current element - I can't use 'this' on it's own as I need to use the actual values elsewhere):

```
$("a,img,p").mouseenter(function (event) {
   nameX = this.tagName;
   indexX = $(nameX).index(this);
   $(''+nameX+':eq('+indexX+')').text("hello");
});

<ul>
  <li>
     <a href="">bullet 1  
        <img src="http://bit.ly/ZqJ1DL"  width="229" height="129"/>
     </a><br>  
     <a href="">bullet 2  
     </a><br>  
     <a href="">bullet 3
     </a><br>
     general text
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I use the above - it DOES work when hovering over bullet 2 or bullet 3.

However, it does NOT work with bullet 1 - here the JS replaces ALL contents of the parent, including the image - I only want it to replace the TEXT and leave the image (and any other children) alone, regardless of the position of the the text.

See example [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/stevepitman/esauq/1/)

[EDIT: the above HTML is example code - it could be anything as it will be the code of the 3rd party website I'm hovering over - please therefore comment on the JQuery code only - thanks, Steve]

Comment: what if you have something like this: `text here <img /> more text here` ?

Comment: Brian, I don't understand what you mean I'm afraid. It's the JQuery code I have the problem with - the HTML code is just shown as an example.

Comment: I know, I'm asking if you had that HTML I posted.. what would you expect the result to be?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean - I've added your HTML (http://jsfiddle.net/stevepitman/esauq/5/) and in doing a 'mouseenter' it still replaces the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this script selects all DOM elements within the anchor so it can replace them when changing the text:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function (event) {
  nameX = this.tagName;
  indexX = $(nameX).index(this);

  var elem = $('' + nameX + ':eq(' + indexX + ')');  
  var internals = $("*", elem);  
  elem.html("")
      .append(internals)
      .append("hello");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vvtgQ/

and here is a version that uses jQuery.contents() to work only on :text elements:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function (event) {
  nameX = this.tagName;
  indexX = $(nameX).index(this);

  var elem = $('' + nameX + ':eq(' + indexX + ')');
  elem.contents().each(function(index, item) {    
    if(item.nodeType == 3)
    {
      item.nodeValue = "hello";
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eYSXp/

Comment: btw, you will need to be careful with the original selector `$("a,img,p")` because that will replace the IMG tag within the A tag in the Bullet 1 example. if you know the parent tag, you can use the child selector like this (if the parent will always be a `li`): `$("li  > a, li > img, li > p")`

Comment: what if text was before the image?  Just saying :P

Comment: Dave - that's fantastic - it works a treat - thank you! Just for my understanding, your code stores the original contents then puts them back in the element before appending the new 'hello' - how does your code know the POSITION of where to insert that new 'hello'?

Comment: it actually doesn't, it is just appending to the end. as @wirey suggests, if text is before the image it will move it to the end. in order to preserve the order, you'd need to use jQuery's `contents()` function instead of the selector, and then loop through each element in the collection looking for text elements. slightly more complex.

Comment: add another example that uses `jQuery.contents()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this got answered already but:

```
$("a,p").mouseenter(function (event) {  
  nameX = this.tagName;
  indexX = $(nameX).index(this);
  runningText = $(''+nameX+':eq('+indexX+')').text();
  runningText = runningText.replace(/\W/g, ' ');
  while (runningText.charAt(runningText.length-1) == " ") {
    runningText = runningText.substr(0, runningText.length-1);
  }
  newText = "hello";
  newHTML = $(this).html();
  newHTML = newHTML.replace(runningText, newText);
  $(this).html(newHTML);  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/esauq/36/